# jquery hide show list elements with a select

Tags: jquery-selectors, show-hide

I'm stuck on something that I think should be easy... I've got a select that on change gets the id value and im tring to hide all   and show th ones that with the same id value
so  it works just with the first  
any help me please

```
<select name="" id="estado_list">
 <option value="0">-</option>
 <option value="1">Nuevo León</option>
 <option value="2">Puebla</option>
</select>


<ul style="list-style: none outside none;">
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="1">data</li>
 <li class="forli" id="2">data</li>
</ul>






 $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#estado_list").change(function(){  
         var id = $(this).val();

          if (id == 0 ){$('.forli').show();}
       else{$('.forli').hide();
            $('li').each(function(){
             $('#'+ id).show();

         });
         }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: You have the same id being used over and over, as well as being a number. Both practices are wrong. You should use classnames instead, and don't start them with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id fields should be unique and will cause problems when accessed from the DOM object. Try using the class field instead.

```
<select name="" id="estado_list">
 <option value="list0">-</option>
 <option value="list1">Nuevo León</option>
 <option value="list2">Puebla</option>
</select>


<ul style="list-style: none outside none;">
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list1">data</li>
 <li class="forli list2">data</li>
</ul>


 $(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#estado_list").change(function(){  
      $('.forli').hide().filter("."+$(this).val()).show();
   });
 });
```

Comment: @morris you can mark either Jonathan's answer or mine so the community is aware that the problem has been solved correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your markup so as to not use numbers for `id` values, as well as not use the same `id` over and over. I would encourage you to make further use of class values:

```
<select id="estado_list">
 <option value="zero">-</option>
 <option value="one">Nuevo León</option>
 <option value="two">Puebla</option>
</select>

<ul>
 <li class="forli one">1</li>
 <li class="forli one">2</li>
 <li class="forli one">3</li>
 <li class="forli one">4</li>
 <li class="forli one">5</li>
 <li class="forli one">6</li>
 <li class="forli two">7</li>
</ul>​
```

Once you've done this, you can filter the the results when your select changes:

```
$("#estado_list").on("change", function(e){
    $("li.forli").each(function(){
      $(this).toggle( $(this).hasClass( e.target.value ) );  
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JtFvK/1/